# Too long query time execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I use this query in order to calculate year to date. But it took too much time to be executed.

How to optimize it?

```
SELECT T.[Sales_Organization],
       T.[CD_DossierMagnitude],
       T.[DS_DossierMagnitude],
       T.[Sales_Product_Name_N3],
       T.[Sales_Product_Name_N2],
       T.[Sales_Product_Name_N1],
       T.[Market_Segment_Name_N2],
       T1.*
FROM   stg.Fact_EPV_SEFPRO_DC T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM([QTY])     AS QTY_YTD,
                           SUM([QTY_UoM]) AS QTY_UoM_YTD,
                           SUM([PNV_LC])  AS PNV_LC_YTD,
                           SUM([Vmvu])    AS Vmvu_YTD
                    FROM   stg.Fact_DC
                    WHERE  [Delivery_Year] = T.[Delivery_Year]
                           AND Delivery_month <= t.Delivery_month
                           AND Sales_Organization = T.Sales_Organization
                           AND Sales_Product_Name_N3 = T.Sales_Product_Name_N3
                           AND Sales_Product_Name_N2 = T.Sales_Product_Name_N2
                           AND Sales_Product_Name_N1 = T.Sales_Product_Name_N1
                           AND Market_Segment_Name_N2 = T.Market_Segment_Name_N2
                           AND Market_Grp = T.Market_Grp
                           AND Product_Name_SOA = T.Product_Name_SOA
                           AND Doc_Currency = T.Doc_Currency) t1
```

Comment: Past time to upgrade SQL Server so you can both use supported software and have access to more powerful window functions.

Comment: Also try to check Execution Plan, https://www.sqlshack.com/using-the-sql-execution-plan-for-query-performance-tuning/

Comment: Triangular joins can get very expensive. Unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 does not support Cumulative Sum functionality, which 2012+ does. You *could* have a look at the [quirky update](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten), but otherwise if all your indexing is good, then you're at the limit of the technology you are using: AKA (like Gordon said) time to upgrade. 2008 is about to run out of support anyway (on 9 July 2019), so there's no time like the present.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? To optimise for this specific query would need something like `(Sales_Organization, Sales_Product_Name_N3, Sales_Product_Name_N2,Sales_Product_Name_N1, Market_Segment_Name_N2,  Market_Grp Product_Name_SOA,Doc_Currency,Delivery_Year, Delivery_month) INCLUDE(QTY,QTY_UoM,PNV_LC,Vmvu)`. So each seek would be able to go exactly  to the rows that need to be summed (maximum 12)